# Parsing dockerfile through regex

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a task to set up dockerfile parsing. It is necessary to check whether the image is proxied from dockerfile and if not, then add the address of my repository my.repo.org to the image.
for example, my dockerfile with multiple images:

```
FROM my.repo.org/3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-19
...
###############################################
FROM alpine:3.14
...
################################################
```

I need to check the name of the image, and if my repository my.repo.org does not exist, then add it to the desired image, and if there is, then do not change anything. What would become:

```
FROM my.repo.org/3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-19
...
###############################################
FROM my.repo.org/alpine:3.14
...
################################################
```

I tried using sed and awk, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `sed` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
FROM my.repo.org/3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-19
...
###############################################
FROM alpine:3.14
...
################################################
```

then

```
sed -e '/^FROM my[.]repo[.]org/{p;d}' -e 's/^FROM /FROM my.repo.org\//' file.txt
```

gives output

```
FROM my.repo.org/3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-19
...
###############################################
FROM alpine:3.14
...
################################################
```

Explanation: I give 2 instruction to GNU `sed`, if line starts with `FROM my.repo.org` (observe that I use `[.]` to denote literal dot, not any character) then it should print as is (`p`) and proceed to next line (`d`) therefore such line will never be altered and to replace staring `FROM`  using `FROM my.repo.org/`, note that `/` needs to be escaped to avoid being considering delimiter.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8)*

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` conditional clauses:

```
awk '/^FROM/ && $2 !~/^my\.repo\.org/{ $2="my.repo.org/"$2 }1;' dockerfile
```

---

```
FROM my.repo.org/3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-19
...
###############################################
FROM my.repo.org/alpine:3.14
...
################################################
```